# Angular CLI 6.0.0 - Failing to generate components

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

After updating Angular CLI to v6.0.0 and creating a new app using `ng new my-app` I receive the following error when attempting to generate a component with `ng g c my-component`:

`Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.`

*This is the simple error returned in Terminal, VSCode gives a much more verbose error which i can paste if necessary!*

I can find reference to this error [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6566) and have tried adjusting the 'root' value in 'angular.json' to both "" and "src" but with no success.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you add the folder structure and under which module you are planning to create the component `my-component`

Comment: @Aravind Attempting to create the new component in `project/src/app` directory. It's a completely new app created using CLI so has standard folder structure and only app.module.

Comment: @SamScholefield: Are you able to generate the new component when running/using the following command: **`ng g c my-component --skip-import`** or **`ng g c my-component --skip-import=true`**?

Comment: @k.vincent Using `--skip-import` created the component and placed it in the project root folder in a 'users' directory

Comment: @SamScholefield: Ok, that at least one good news. Then you could create a new folder where you would like to put the new generated component, and then remove it from the root. But don't forget to add new component in the declaration array in `app.module.ts`. Should be then e.g.: `import { NewComponent } from './YourNewFolder/new.component';` `@NgModule({ declarations: [ AppComponent, NewComponent ],  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a bug report for @angular/cli and it got merged into github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10653.

This issue appears to have been fixed in the 6.0.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

I know your struggle I've just finished dealing with it myself. 
What fixed it for me was using 
`sudo ng generate component your-component`

hopefully that fixes your problem as well and tells you there's a problem with file permissions

Comment: I opened a bug report for @angular/cli and it got merged into https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10653 so this issue has been dealt with and fixed in v6.0.1 - uninstalling @angular/cli and installing @angular/cli@6.0.1